# Understanding l_ply from plyr

Tags: r, plyr

From the documentation:

> All output is discarded. This is useful for functions that you are calling purely for their side effects like displaying plots or saving output.

I've spent some time playing around and trying to find a suitable use case but haven't(yet).

Looking at the examples hasn't helped me better understand it.

Sample usage:

```
l_ply(iris[1:5,1], function(x) print(summary(x)))
```

This will work.

However, under what circumstances might one need to print and then discard these results?

Comment: The example are simplified, in particular because side effects are not desirable in package examples. Typical functions passed would be plot, save, write.table ... All of these have (more) usefull side effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following

```
X <- matrix (c (rnorm (50)), ncol = 5);
```

Assume each colmn of `X` indicates a series which you want to overplot.
You can do it as following, by first creating an empty plot and then plotting the series corresponding to each column, using `lapply`. Although `lapply` will return the values returned by the `plot` call that we do not want.

```
plot (NULL, ylim = range (X), xlim = c (1, nrow (X)));
lapply (1:ncol (X), function (i) points (X[,i], type = "o", col = i));
```

Instead you can use

```
plot (NULL, ylim = range (X), xlim = c (1, nrow (X)));
l_ply (1:ncol (X), function (i) points (X[,i], type = "o", col = i));
```

This has the same effect but does not return the values returned by `plot`. Here, the "side effect" is the `plot` function plotting on the device.